# JOLT Transformation - Pivot

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm trying to transform the following JSON

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Buy",
    "List": [
      {
        "x": "7/8/2021",
        "y": 462853
      },
      {
        "x": "7/9/2021",
        "y": 462777
      },
      {
        "x": "7/10/2021",
        "y": 462701
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Statistical",
    "List": [
      {
        "x": "7/8/2021",
        "y": 462853
      },
      {
        "x": "7/9/2021",
        "y": 462777
      },
      {
        "x": "7/10/2021",
        "y": 462701
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Sell",
    "List": [
      {
        "x": "7/8/2021",
        "y": 462853
      },
      {
        "x": "7/9/2021",
        "y": 462777
      },
      {
        "x": "7/10/2021",
        "y": 462701
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Into something simpler like this, using JOLT:

```json
[
  {
     "Date": "7/8/2021",
     "Buy": 462853,
     "Statistical": 462853,
     "Sell": 462853
  },
  {
     "Date": "7/9/2021",
     "Buy": 462777,
     "Statistical": 462777,
     "Sell": 462777
  },
  {
     "Date": "7/10/2021",
     "Buy": 462701,
     "Statistical": 462701,
     "Sell": 462701
  }
]
```

I try a lot of jolt code but I can't figure out how to do the last part.
I wrote some jolt transformation like this:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "List": {
          "*": {
            "@(2,name)": "[&(3)].&1.name",
            "x": "[&(3)].&1.Date",
            "y": "[&(3)].&1.NAV"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But I don't know how to do the final part to pivot the name column. The value of the name column should pivot based on NAV value.

Comment: You can check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44262429/transform-json-json-jolt

Comment: The name in the inner element is irrelevant. I don't need that field. I edited the question and remove that field.  @BarbarosÖzhan

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhedri, The post you mention is another issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accumulate the key-value pairs of `name` keys by `x` values as represented by `Date` key within the **shift** transformation, and then pick leftmost one of the elements of each arrays those already have repeatedly same elements throughout within each by using **cardinality** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "List": {
          "*": {
            "x": "[&1].Date",
            "y": "[&1].@(3,name)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Date": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You're amazing. I didn't use cardinality before. I'm going to read more about what can be done with it.